# Incoming Chat Pop Notification when app is backgrounded/foregrounded or the phone is locked in Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am currently working on text chat application built with Xamarin Forms, i have a requirement to display a full screen page once a chat is initiated, a whatsapp incoming call notification is an analogy here. I do have push notifications setup, so i do receive a push notification once a chat is initiated but I can't find a way to display a full screen custom page with controls to accepting/rejecting a chat. This page needs to appear in foreground mode/background mode or when the phone is locked. Any lead would be helpful. At the moment I am really keen to solve this for android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to appear full screen after you click the notification in lock screen without unlock the device?

Comment: Actually, I want my full screen page(content page) with Accept/Reject controls to appear immediately after the push notification for a new chat has been received by the application. I don't want these controls to appear after the user clicks the notification from the notification drawer. So these chats need to responded asap and its critical that we present the user the option to accept the chat immediately.

Comment: As my research, I think it cannot be achieved.